# Is Redis a good option for a use case on managing the ticket status updates

Tags: redis

I have been exploring couple of options for a use case where in we have to track multiple status updates for tickets generated as part of a TMS. One ticket (parent ticket) can have sub tickets associated to it (like child elements) and a parent ticket will only be considered as closed once all the child tickets would have status closed. The status of the tickets can have 4 different status options like (new open, closed, pending).

Ex:- ParentTicket No -1234(parent) underneath this we have 4 more sub tickets each having one status from the list{new, open, closed, pending} as 
SubTicket1 no - 1234_2345.1 
SubTicket2 no - 1234_5543.2
SubTicket3 no - 1234_4567.3
SubTicket4 no - 1234_9876.4

So the final structure looks like this :

ParentTicket No -1234 "Status = **Open**"
  -SubTicket1 no - 1234_2345.1 "Status = **New**"
  -SubTicket2 no - 1234_5543.2 "Status = **closed**"
  -SubTicket3 no - 1234_4567.3 "Status = **pending**"
  -SubTicket4 no - 1234_9876.4 "Status = **New**"

There would be around 250K Such (parent) tickets in a day which we need to manage and for a period of 1 year. Typical life cycle of a ticket can be between 1minute to 1 year. This looks a bit shitty, but yes that is the requirement. Off-course we can destroy the tickets those have closed status after some time.

To solve this problem I am considering to go with REDIS using hash for the Parent Ticket number and storing SubticketNos as a key in it with value = status. I know there are couple of more ways to deal this problem and would appreciate if some pointers can be provided around this.

Thanks in advance champs!

Comment: Seems like a solid design imo - just make sure you have enough RAM to store a year's worth of tickets

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, redis is awesome for manage sessions for example, but finally, data without a lot of importance if this data is destroyed for some strange reasons.

In your case, you need a good performance without kill "relations" (relational databases for example), so, my proposal to keep a good ratio about read, inserts and transactions could be Orient DB. Orient DB is a really cool storage system to use in your case (internally is a graph database but you will manage it as a document database, like mongo db): http://orientdb.com/

Comment: Thanks Jose, looks interesting. I will have a look around it. But I don't want to discount Redis completely as we have already have some stuff done on it so would be easy for us to extend the solution. Excited to know that how OrientDB make sure that the data is not lost without killing the performance. Wherein REDIS for hashes confirm O(1).